# Regular Expression to match {asdf} but not {{asdf}}

Tags: regex, vbscript

I have a very straightforward problem.

I am using this regular expression to match instances of `{somestring}`.

```
\{{1}(\w+?)\}{1}
```

The problem is that I need it to ignore instances of `{{somestring}}`, but of course, it is matching the inner `{somestring}` in `{{somestring}}`.

Any idea how I can tweak the expression to skip anything like `{{somestring}}`?

I am using vbscript's regular expression engine.

Comment: What regex engine/language are you using?

Comment: Something like: `[^\{]\{(\w+?)\}[^\}]`

Comment: @Tomas I don't think so. It will still match `{somestring}` inside `{{somestring}}`

Comment: Apologies - I am using vbscript. Updated question with that info too.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - that does the trick BUT it matches 1 extra character on both the left and right of what should be matched, where the 1 extra character isn't { on the left and } on the right.

Comment: @cbwdev you cannot entirely avoid that. see my edit

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your regex engine supports [lookarounds](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), they are the way to go:

```
(?<!\{)\{\w+\}(?!\})
```

This does literally what you want. The lookbehind asserts that there is no `{` preceding your `{`, and the lookahead asserts that there is no `}` following your `}`.

Note that `{1}` does never do anything. Ever.

Also note that you don't need to make `\w+` ungreedy, because it cannot consume `}` anyway.

Finally, I just want to put it here, that an alternative to escaping `{` and `}` is to put it into a one-character character class. It's a matter of taste which one you prefer but I like the readability of this one better:

```
(?<![{])[{]\w+[}](?![}])
```

**EDIT:**

[It seems like VBScript does not support lookbehinds.](http://www.regular-expressions.info/vbscript.html)

That is a bit of an issue. The closest thing you can get is:

```
(^|[^{])[{]\w+[}](?![}])
```

However, if the match is not found at the beginning of the string, this will include the preceding character in the match. This alone is not a problem, because you could get rid of that character through capturing of substring functions or something. However, matches cannot overlap, so if you have an input like `{some}{string}` you won't easily get both matches (because the first `}` has to be part of the second match). Some engines provide `\G` as the equivalent of `^` for continuing matches, but VBScript does not seem to support that either. Hence, it's going to get ugly from here on.

What you could do is to exclude the closing `}` from the match (using another lookahead):

```
(^|[^{])[{]\w+(?=[}](?![}]))
```

Now you will get matches `{some` and `}{string`, so will have to append every match with `}` and remove the first character from every match that is not at the beginning of your string. Or if you can get hold of the captured results, you can use

```
(^|[^{])([{]\w+)(?=[}](?![}]))
```

Then retrieve capturing group `2` and append `}`.

Comment: I don't think this works with vbscript regex engine. I also tried it in the tester at http://regexpal.com/ and it also didn't work.

Comment: oooh, the last expression and idea in your solution is a brilliant workaround!  This solution will work perfectly for me in this particular case. Thanks very much for your insight. It is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

This expression works perfectly:

```
^{{1}(\w+?)}{1}$
```

Answer (score 0):

In this particular case, you can use **^**{{1}(\w+?)}{1}**$** - that would match {something}, but won't match {{something}}, but it also won't match for `something else and {something} after that` . If you want the last string match your regex, the previous answer is  exactly what you need.